# Not able to map records in csv into objects of a class in Scala / Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a jupyter notebook running a spylon-kernel (Scala / Spark).

Currently, I try to load records from a csv into a RDD and then map each record into objects of the "Weather" class as follows:

```
val lines = scala.io.Source.fromFile("/path/to/nycweather.csv").mkString
println(lines)

val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)

//Next, you need to import a library for creating a SchemaRDD. Type this:
import sqlContext.implicits._

//Create a case class in Scala that defines the schema of the table. Type in:
case class Weather(date: String, temp: Int, precipitation: Double)

//Create the RDD of the Weather object:
val weather = sc.textFile("/path/to/nycweather.csv").map(_.split(",")). map(w => Weather(w(0), w(1).trim.toInt, w(2).trim.toDouble)).toDF()

//It all works fine until the last line above.
//But when I run this line of code:
weather.first()
```

It all bursts out with the following error message

[image: error obtained after weather.first()]

the message has a couple more lines but I omitted to be more visible.

Could someone indicate why am I getting this error and suggest code changes to solve it?

Comment: The code is correct. there may be mistake in defining "case class Weather(date: String, temp: Int, precipitation: Double)"

Answer (score 1):

You are using older RDD syntax for reading a CSV. There is an easier way to read a CSV as

```
    val weather1 = spark.read.csv("path to nycweather.csv").toDF("date","temp","precipitation")
    weather1.show()
```

Input file contains following data

```
1/1/2010,30,35.0
2/4/2015,35,27.9
```

Result

```
+--------+----+-------------+
|    date|temp|precipitation|
+--------+----+-------------+
|1/1/2010|  30|         35.0|
|2/4/2015|  35|         27.9|
+--------+----+-------------+
```

Comment: I was able to send the result of your line straight to Spark SQL, which was the final goal of the notebook. But I still was not able to execute the mapping task I mentioned in the post. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Please share full code, i think the case class is not in scope